# How to subset an SRA file for a single chromosome?

Tags: assembly, reference-genome, pacbio, sratoolkit

I used prefetch to get the Pacbio reads of chicken from the SRA database. I want to align these reads against a reference genome, but not all the reads. I am only interested in a particular region on Chromosome Z. Is there a way that I can subset the downloaded SRA file?

I am trying to use blast, but don't know where to start. How should I prepare the SRA file from prefetch for the blast? I have currently started fasterq-dump for the downloaded SRA file.

Or should I subset after aligning the entire SRA reads data with the reference genome, and in that case what tools do I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dumping out the reads using `fasterq-dump`, you'll need to align them first and then extract those that map to your region of interest. I think [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) is an excellent choice. If you have HiFi reads, you can just use something like:

```
minimap2 -ax map-hifi ref.fa pacbio-ccs.fq.gz > aln.sam
```

Then, using [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html), coordinate-[sort](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-sort.html) and [index](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-index.html) the sorted alignments:

```
samtools sort -o aln.sorted.bam aln.sam
samtools index aln.sorted.bam
```

With an indexed BAM, you can then [view](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-view.html) the alignments that overlap your region of interest:

```
samtools view aln.sorted.bam chrZ:1-10000
```

If you instead write these to a file, you can then convert them using samtools  [fasta](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-fasta.html). I think something like the following should suffice:

```
samtools view -bo chrZ_1_10000.bam aln.sorted.bam chrZ:1-10000
samtools fasta -0 chrZ_1_10000.fa -o /dev/null chrZ_1_10000.bam
```

You could then upload the FASTA file to the NCBI [Web BLAST](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) server.

Comment: "After dumping out the reads using prefetch". Do you mean after fasterq-dump ends? And what will be looking at once that ends, a set of fastq files?

Comment: @venkateshwar Typo, sorry! Yes, or likely just a single FASTQ file since these are PacBio long reads.